# sas: recode a bunch of variables at once

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

Let's say I have 10 variables, all with the same prefix (they start with `com`).

Let's say the variables are binary, and there is some missing data, and I'd like to set all that missing data to 0. I'd like to generate a new variable for each original variable so the original data is intact.

How would I go about recoding all of these variables at once? Is there an easy way to run a loop in SAS? If this were Python or R I could write a loop to do it all using `grep` or something similar.

**EDIT:** Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to use an unindexed array with the `com` variables to create copies of them called `new_com` (prefix each variable with `new`). Then I just want to recode, which I know I can do using `if` `then` statements. The first part, about cloning the variables, is where I am stuck.

Comment: You could either define each new variable with an if statement e.g
 if com1 = . then com1_nm =0; else com1_nm = com1;

or as this will be pretty repetitive, you could use do loops and arrays to save you writing out so much code.
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/158-2010.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but there are two issues: I need to rename the variables, using a prefix, and I'd rather not have to list each one individually in the array but rather use some wildcard. Any insight as to how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Below is edited in the event you do not know how many variables you have but know the prefix you want:

```
data test;
    input coma comet compton communism come comb community comerade complete comma;
    datalines;
    1   1   1   0   0   .   0   0   1   .
    ;
run;

%let prefix=com;

/* output the list of variables and only keep those with prefix */
proc contents data = test noprint out=names(keep=name varnum); run;

proc sort data = names;
    by varnum;
run;

/* create your new variable with a "new_" prefix */
data names1; set names;
    if index(name,"&prefix.");
    new_name = "new_"||strip(name);
run;

/* put lists into macro variables */
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into: old_vars separated by " "
    from names1;

    select new_name
    into: new_vars separated by " "
    from names1;

    select count(*)
    into: nobs
    from names1;
quit;

%put &old_vars.;
%put &new_vars.;
%put &nobs.;

/* use array and macro variables to manipulate data */
data test1; set test;
    array old(&nobs.) &old_vars.;
    array new(&nobs.) &new_vars.;
        do i=1 to &nobs.;
            if old(i) = . then new(i) = 0;
                else new(i) = old(i);
        end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Comment: What if I don't? Is there a way to tell SAS to find the length of `old`?

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect that. All you need to know is your prefix and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have SAS/STAT licensed, this is most simply done using `PROC STDIZE`:

```
data have;
  array com[10];
  call streaminit(7);
  do _j = 1 to 10;
    do _i = 1 to 10;
      if rand('Uniform') < 0.2 the com[_i]=.;
      else com[_i]=1;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc stdize data=have out=have_zero missing=0 reponly sprefix=new_ oprefix=old_;
  var com:;
run;
```

`reponly` says to not do any standardization (only impute zero for missing), `sprefix` and `oprefix` specify what to prefix standardized and original variables with.

Comment: And if you want the original variables to keep their names use OPREFIX with no prefix option.

Comment: Edit: Hmm, it didn't work the _first_ time I did it, but now it does...